# does the series $\frac{\ln(n^{n})}{n!}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series converge ?

My attempt: 
$$\frac{\ln(n^{n})}{n!} = \frac{n \, \ln(n)}{(n-1)!} $$ and we known $\forall x  \geqslant 0$, $$\ln(1+x)\leqslant x$$ and $$  \ln(n) = \ln(1+(n-1)) \leqslant  n -1.$$

Comment: First, your expression is not a series, but a sequence.  Second, $\ln(a/b)\neq \ln(a)/b$.

Comment: Grrrr. Silently changing the question is bad practice !

Comment: The title doesn't match the question.

Comment: excuse me it was an mistake

Comment: So to clarify, are you asking about $\ln(n^n)$ or $\ln(n)^n$ for the numerator (they're not equal) ?

Comment: done , it's $ln(n^{n})$

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln\dfrac{n^n}{n!}=-n\cdot\dfrac1n\sum_{r=1}^n\ln\dfrac rn$$

Now $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1n\sum_{r=1}^n\ln\dfrac rn=\int_0^1\ln x\ dx$$

Comment: please i just update my question ,  can you recheck ?

Answer (score 1):

**Without words:**

$$n=8\to\frac{n^n}{n!}=\frac{8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8}>\frac{8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8}{4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8}=2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2=2^{n/2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

By ratio test

$$\frac{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{n\ln n}=\frac1n \frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}\to 0$$